# How do i set the tab icon effect like facebook app?

Tags: android

I have three icons `A` `B` `C` for my tab layout , i want that user click tab A, it will change color , when user click tab `B` that tab `A` will change to original.

My problem is that i can't let the tab icon change to original ,when it becomes yellow , it will always be yellow , how do i fix this problem ? Thanks in advance.

```
public class HomeTabs extends Fragment {

    private Context context;

    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    // Here is my three icons
    private int[] imageResId = {R.drawable.contract,
            R.drawable.table,
            R.drawable.line_graph};

    public HomeTabs() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static HomeTabs newInstance(){return new HomeTabs();}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home_tabs, container, false);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(getResources().getString(R.string.tab1)));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(getResources().getString(R.string.tab2)));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(getResources().getString(R.string.tab3)));
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager)view.findViewById(R.id.viewPagerDataReport);

        ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);

        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        // Add my three icons
        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(imageResId[0]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(imageResId[1]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(imageResId[2]);

        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
                // When user click the tab position , change its color
                int id =tab.getPosition();
                if (id==0){
                    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.YELLOW, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
                    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(imageResId[1]);
                    tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(imageResId[2]);
                }
                if (id==1){
                    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(imageResId[0]);
                    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.YELLOW, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
                    tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(imageResId[2]);
                }
                if (id==2){
                    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(imageResId[0]);
                    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(imageResId[1]);
                    tabLayout.getTabAt(2).getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.YELLOW, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
                }
                //tab.getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.YELLOW, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                //tab.getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#a8a8a8"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bcz you are not changing color when you click other tab. you are only setting color to perticular tab position. so rest will be yellow.

try like this.

```
    if (id==0){
          tabLayout.getTabAt(0).getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.YELLOW, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
          tabLayout.getTabAt(1).getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
          tabLayout.getTabAt(2).getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
          tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(imageResId[1]);
          tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(imageResId[2]);
                    }
```

or you can do like this.

```
    if (position == 0) {
        tabOne.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.windowBackground));
        tabOne.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.image_yellow, 0, 0);    
    }else {
      tabOne.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.tab_background_selected));
      tabOne.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.image_colorFul, 0, 0);
        }
```

> tabOne is a textview.    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(tabOne);

Comment: Thanks for your help Sagar ,  it works fine , but i have another problem that will change my icon to white , if my icon is colorful how do i hold it ?

Comment: than change color to your color.. its simple.  your color instead of Color.WHITE .

Comment: I mean if my icon is not single color , how to handle it ?  Thanks for your reply.

Comment: than you should use 2 icon .. one colorful icon and second yellow icon, and dont use setColorFilter.. check my updated answer.

Comment: 2 icon...I got the point now !  Sagar Thanks for your help truly. Blessing.

Comment: you are welcome.. you can approve if its helpful and satisfying answer.